# snowflake datarobot oauth connection

Tags: oauth, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datarobot

I am trying to connect to Snowflake with DataRobot with oauth.

In order to do that I am first trying to create security integration.

```
CREATE SECURITY INTEGRATION DataRobot
TYPE = OAUTH
ENABLED = TRUE
OAUTH_CLIENT = DataRobot
OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = 'https://app.datarobot.com/account/snowflake/snowflake_authz_return';
```

and I am getting this error:

> SQL compilation error: invalid value [DataRobot] for parameter 'OAUTH_CLIENT'

The same commands work when I try to create integration for looker, with `oauth_clint = looker`, but I am not aware of what oauth_client should I provide for datarobot.

Can anybody suggest how to address the issue and how to see the list of oauth_clint supported by Snowflake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this issue is "DataRobot" is considered as a custom OAUTH client and for that reason OAUTH_CLIENT = custom should be used.

Looker is a partner client for Snowflake, hence the client name is available to be used.

Documentation for this is here :

SF Partner applications (Looker) : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-partner.html

SF Custom OAuth application : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-custom.html